# Trigger when change is happening in specific sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with data that is imported through IMPORTRANGE to another sheet. When I make changes to Spreadsheet 1 >>> Spreadsheet 2 I have a script that copy the data from Copy to Paste. It is working all fine however I want to make sure that the script only runs when changes are made in the  'Copy' sheet and not any other. At the moment it runs independent on what sheet I make changes in.

[Spreadsheet 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S_ZHUuFZheOLrUIbOocR5lwfPNhBQmzHuAsG29vQV_k/edit#gid=0)
[Spreadsheet2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eEj2xXSJABzkTBz3-al49MWBA4XL1eaMNDe4QtvQSnM/edit#gid=0)

I tried onChange trigger two different ways...
This one makes the change but triggers when changes are made in any of the sheets

```
function Trigger2(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() === 'Copy') {

copyInfo();

}
}
```

AND
(this does not work)

```
function Trigger2(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if( sheet.getActiveSheet().getName() !== "Copy" ) return;{

copyInfo();

}}
```

The copy code looks like this...

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Copy");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Paste");

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange(2,1,12,8);
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(2,1,12,8);

  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination);
}
```

Comment: You can take a look at my answer.  I've worked with the onChange event a lot and it will work in the situation as you wish but it cannot really be used to identify the sheet that has changed.  So trying to do the same thing with another pair of sheets will be difficult because you wont know which sheet caused the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Copy Changes from one Sheet To Another after Imported Range Changes

Spreadsheet 2 Imports a range to Sheet1 from Spreadsheet 1 Sheet1 and when a change occurs in Spreadsheet 2 Sheet1 we copy data from Spreadsheet2 Sheet1 to Spreadsheet2 Sheet 2.

```
function onMyChange(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));//useful during setup
  //e.source.toast("Entry");//useful during setup
  const sh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  Logger.log(sh.getName());
  if(e.changeType == "OTHER") {
    let tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); 
    sh.getRange(2,1,12,8).copyTo(tsh.getRange(2,1));//Only need the upper left hand corner of the range.   Thus you change change the size of the source data without having to change the target range.
  }
}
```

One might be inclined to attempt to use e.source.getActiveSheet() unfortunately this does not necessary get the sheet that you have written unless in is SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0].  onChange event object always returns the most left sheet in the spreadsheet in this situation so it can't be used to identify the sheet that is being written to from the importRange function.

With this function you no longer require another function.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. It was way past my abilites, so your help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A simple `if` should work, but you're trying to compare the name to the wrong field. According to Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), the `source` field in the Event Object `e` returns the *Spreadsheet* object, which is the entire document.

Instead you can use the `e.range` field, which contains the exact range where the edit was made, and the `Range` class has a [`getSheet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getsheet) method to get the parent Sheet.

So you can modify your sample to the following:

```
function Trigger2(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() === 'Copy') {//Edit: this will only work if sheet is the most left sheet in the spreadsheet
    copyInfo();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that but it still doesn't work for some reason. It just says it has failed executions for some reasons.

Comment: I tested it with just a simple alert and it worked. Maybe the copy function is failing. What error are you getting? You can click the Executions tab on the left side and click the failed executions to see the error message.

Comment: It says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined"

Comment: Are you trying to test it by clicking the "Run" button? Since this is a trigger the `e` variable will only have data when you actually edit the sheet. You can try to rename the function to `onEdit(e)` to set it up as a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), then try it live on the sheet by editing a cell.

Comment: I think I am over complicating things for myself. Instead of copying my content to a second tab I will copy it into a seperate spreadhseet and I don't have to worry about anyone messing with any other tabs and firing the code by mistake. Thanks anyway very much for your time.

Comment: There is no e.range  with an onChange event object and e.source.getActiveSheet() always returns SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0] so it's relatively useless.  The good news is the the change in data in the source spreadsheet does trigger the onChange trigger.

Comment: Here's what the onChange event object looks like `{"authMode":"FULL","changeType":"OTHER","source":{},"triggerUid":""}`

Comment: `onChange` doesn't have a range field but `onEdit` does. It's documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)