# Automatically copy values from an importrange column to another column before it updates

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, import, conditional-formatting

I have [a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FC2CpRgcpnwrXEqV9MoQRJijLa3Eg9VQfOSHxERssY4/edit?usp=sharing) that tracks Google rankings. The rankings column uses IMPORTRANGE to grab the current rankings from a live sheet from the service provider. That live sheet gets updated every night.

I want to add a new column that shows the previous week's rankings for comparison.

Is there a way for that new column to grab values from the rankings column on a specific day and time? That would allow it to always capture the previous weeks values and save it.

Or is there any other suggestions to achieve this? Like grabbing the values based on edit history 7 days before? No idea if there's a feature for that.

Comment: possible only with script

Comment: Use onChange trigger with changeType="OTHER"

Comment: @Cooper please can you elaborate on that? I've never heard of it. I've made the sheet editable if it's something you could possibly demonstrate.

Comment: I don't have a need to demonstrate it.  I offered you a path to a solution. If you wish to do the research and implement it that's up to you.  Starting [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) [past example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71553008/7215091)